# In Talend how to give the tfilerowcount value to input of the MySQL query?

Tags: talend

I'm a beginner to Talend. I have stopped at one point in my requirement.

My requirement is I have to pass the `filecount` value to MySQL query on `LIMIT` Clause. Ex: if I can get file count from `tfilerowcount` item in talend. Once received this value, I have to pass it to `tMysqlInput` query as

```
select * from table_name limit "+tFileRowCount_1.filecount+";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of rows in a file using below

`(Integer)globalMap.get("tFileRowCount_1_COUNT")`

Hope this would help you out.